# Using AutoHotKey to enter the unicode symbols on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, xorg, autohotkey, unicode, xkb

I'm bilingual user and while writing I use mostly UK keyboard I have this layout set into my computer. However occasionally I want to write something in my native tongue and the math symbols are additional bonus.

On X11 I use combination of xmodmap and XCompose. I'd like to add following bindings to UK mapping:

- <kbd>AltGr+letter</kbd> - letter as if I had polish keyboard set up (say <kbd>AltGr+a</kbd> should send ą to program). I tried to do it in various ways but it result in errors. Please note that they are very near beginning of space (ą have unicode code 261).
- <kbd>Menu+(sequence)</kbd> - various predefined symbols which would mirror the XCompose. They are added bonus. For example <kbd>Menu+(i-n)</kbd>(- represents release and then press) gives ∈ (this is just an example from my XCompose configuration). I consider it added bonus however.

How should I translate it into AutoHotKey script?

Answer (score 1):

To send, for example, a unicode space interspersed with other characters:

```
Send {U+0020}A{U+0020}B{U+0020}C{U+0020}D{U+0020}.{U+0020}.{U+0020}.{U+0020}
```

Answer (score 0):

I´m no AHK expert but I use the script below to add Spanish characters to the AltGR offerings on my EeePC

^!n:: send ñ
^!+n:: send Ñ
^!c:: send ç
^!+n:: send Ç
^!+?:: send ¿
^!+!:: send ¡

Hope you can modify that to suit your requirement. Save it as a text file with .ahk and add it to startup so it´s always available

Comment: For line `^!a:: send ą` it displays "Ä…"

Comment: Sorry that did not work for you. Maybe the autohotkey user forum will be able to help.

Comment: You have to make sure that the script file is encoded in UTF-8 instead of ANSI.